# Eliminate partially duplicate lines by column and keep the last one

Tags: bash, awk, sed, text-processing

I have a file that looks like this:

```
2011-03-21 name001 line1
2011-03-21 name002 line2
2011-03-21 name003 line3
2011-03-22 name002 line4
2011-03-22 name001 line5
```

for each name, I only want its last appearance. So, I expect the result to be:

```
2011-03-21 name003 line3
2011-03-22 name002 line4
2011-03-22 name001 line5
```

Could someone give me a solution with bash/awk/sed?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This code get uniq lines by second field but from the end of file or text (like in your result example)

```
tac temp.txt | sort -k2,2 -r -u
```

Comment: Make sure that the last line of your input file contains a \n otherwise tac will concatenate it with the last but one line

Comment: To specify another separator, use -t: `tac temp.txt | sort -k1,1 -r -u -t@`

Comment: Would you mind explaining the sort parameters `-k2,2`? :)

Comment: @myradio There is good description in wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(Unix)#Columns_or_fields) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(Unix)#Sort_on_multiple_fields)

Answer (score 11):

```
awk '{a[$2]=$0} END {for (i in a) print a[i]}' file
```

---

If order of appearance is important:

- Based on first appearance:

  ```
  awk '!a[$2] {b[++i]=$2} {a[$2]=$0} END {for (i in b) print a[b[i]]}' file
  ```
- Based on last appearance:

  ```
  tac file | awk '!a[$2] {b[++i]=$2} {a[$2]=$0} END {for (i in b) print a[b[i]]}'
  ```

Comment: This is good - simple and robust.  The order of the output does not match the order of the output if that is important though.  Is there an easy way to fix that?

Comment: @Paul yes, but this will result in a much more complex awk program. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Actually, I was meaning just reversing the printing of the array rather than which entry was selected.  So that the output would be in time order:  line 3, line 4, line 5 rather than line 5, line 4, line 3. +1 from me for the first simple answer. Oh wait, yeah - I see that is what you were doing - it does get stupidly complex.

Comment: @Paul oh, I misunderstood :) ... well, you can always pipe its output to `sort`. would be much simpler than trying to cram everything in `awk`.

Comment: I used the simplest one, and add sort on time stamp field after that. Really a good solution, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
sort < bar > foo
uniq  < foo > bar
```

bar now has no duplicated lines

Comment: Given the OP's example, all the lines would be counted as unique.  He only wants the second field to be used to determine uniqueness.

Comment: +1 ...but this answers the title ('bash eliminate duplicate lines' at the moment), which is what Google seemed to use to send me here!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Here's a version that actually answers the question.

```
sort -k 2 filename | while read f1 f2 f3; do if [ ! "$f2" = "$lf2" ]; then echo "$f1 $f2 $f3"; lf2="$f2"; fi; done
```

Comment: I believe awk script implementing the same logic should be more efficient.