# Bash output the line with highest value

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, uniq

my question is pretty much like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429840/bash-eliminate-duplicate-lines) but with one difference; i want the output the line that has highest score on the 3rd tab. my data is like:

```
1.gui  Qxx  16
2.gui  Qxy  23
3.guT  QWS  11
```

and i want to get this:

```
1.gui  Qxy  23
3.guT  QWS  11
```

I used:

```
cat file.f | uniq | cut -d" " -f3 | sort | uniq -d >>out.f
```

but did not get what i want!?

Comment: Can you recheck the input and output? Should the `1.gui...` in the output be `2.gui...`?

Comment: @Raze2dust the numbers are not important for the first tab; they just to represnt line numbers..

Comment: k.. then you should change the `3.guT` to `2.guT` in the output. It is confusing otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `sort`:

```
$ sort -rk3 file             # Sort on column 3, display all results

2.gui  Qxy  23
1.gui  Qxx  16
3.guT  QWS  11

$ sort -rk3 file | head -2   # Sort on column 3, filter number of results

2.gui  Qxy  23
1.gui  Qxx  16

$ sort -rk3 file | uniq      # Sort on column 3, on display unique results 

2.gui  Qxy  23
1.gui  Qxx  16
3.guT  QWS  11
```

`-r` reverse sort, highest first.

`-k3` sort on the 3rd column.

---

If you only want to display line which the 3rd column is greater than some value *(i.e. 15)* then try this using `awk`:

```
awk '$3>15' file | sort -rk3  # Display line where column 3 > 15 and sort

2.gui  Qxy  23
1.gui  Qxx  16
```

Comment: thanks @sudo_O.. after sorting you got only first line, but i want the get all occurrences..

Comment: the thing is, my file has ~10million rows, i do not know how many occurrences for each.. meaning, i do not know how many lines i can get with head..

Comment: If you want all the results just do `sort -rk3 file`

Answer (score 5):

for future users with same question:

do not forget to introduce -n switch to the `-sort` command, or your values are ordered starting from 9999's and followed by 999's etc.. so use

```
sort -rnk3 file
```

and if you want to get only one line with highest value (remove duplicates) use this:

```
sort -rnk3 file | awk '!x[$2]++'
```

and if you have an usual delimiter you can tell `-awk` to notice:

```
sort -rnk3 file | awk -F"[. ]" '!x[$2]++'
```

Comment: Great - I was looking for that specific awk construct which prevents duplicates on a specific field - I do not know if that can be achieved with just bash sort - it seems that `-u` works on the complete line.

Answer (score 0):

This must give you the highest value for those lines where the name is repeated and conserve those lines that have not repeated names.

```
sort -rk3 file | awk '!seen[$1]++' > file_filtered.txt
```